# How to compare 2 columns of unordered lists in 2 separate dataframes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes that have the same structure. Below is the code for dummy data:

```
col1=[1,2,3]
col2=[['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]
col3=[['b','a','c'],['e','d','f'],['i','m','g']]
d1={
    "col1":col1,
    "col2":col2,
}
d2={
    "col1":col1,
    "col2":col3,
}
A= pd.DataFrame(d1)
B= pd.DataFrame(d2)
```

I get 2 dataframes A and B as below:

[image]

[image]

Col2 has unordered lists but both are considered the same if all the elements of A are there in B. I want to compare the col2 of both the dataframes and want to find out the rows which are not equal. For eg, the last row of B has 'm' in it, which is not present in A. So I would want ['i',' m','g'] or '3' of col1  as my o/p. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here they are all equal. Can you provide an example where there is a discrepancy and indicate your expected output? Perhaps you can convert to frozensets and use merge or isin.

Comment: @cs95 I have updated my question for the desired output. Thank you for your query.

Comment: Do all the lists have the same size?

Comment: @DaniMesejo Yes.

Comment: Also you compare row 1 of A with row 1 of B, row 2 with row 2 and so on? for example what would be the output if you had [bac, img, edf] as rows in B?

Comment: @DaniMesejo Yes, the given answer validated my dataframe for having no mismatched columns. But now I have a bigger problem now as the file checker is saying there are missing values. I am figuring that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lists need to be treated without ordering, and in order to test for membership, they must be hashable.

One structure that fits these descriptions is a `frozenset`, this works assuming your lists don't have duplicates. We can filter on B in this manner:

```
B[~B['col2'].map(frozenset).isin(A['col2'].map(frozenset))]

   col1       col2
2     3  [i, m, g]
```

---

If we need to deal with duplicate values, we can subtract `Counter` objects:

```
from collections import Counter
B[(B['col2'].map(Counter) - A['col2'].map(Counter)).astype(bool)]

   col1       col2
2     3  [i, m, g]
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I wanted to validate my dataframe if there were any mismatched lists and there weren't, which sends me back to ground zero. Now I dont know what problem I have in my dataframe. Anyway, thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: @cs95 Is `isin` going to be applied in a element-wise basis? I mean first row of A with first row of B, and so on?

Comment: @DaniMesejo right, these sorts of ops are iterative for object columns. This is nowhere near the ideal level of performance but that's because pandas doesn't make friends with `object`s.

Comment: @Aditya I invite you to look at the About Me section of my profile, it talks about the XY problem which is what I think you might be suffering with.

Comment: @cs95 I did that yesterday itself. Dude you're a pro :) I hope I also become an expert in Pandas one day, just like you. :)